# Error <interface declaration>, <parcelable declaration>, AidlTokenType.import or AidlTokenType.package expected, got '.' in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I Have a Question
this Error
, , AidlTokenType.import or AidlTokenType.package expected, got '.'

is For What thing?

[image]

Before this Error, I add an activity and a layout to my project

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your `MainActivity` is a subclass of `Activity`? Otherwise it wont work.

Answer (score 2):

fellow this step my pro
 1- Open File -> Settings
2-Choose Editor -> Language Injections 
and uncheck the metadata(AIDL) option from the list
Apply, and click OK.

You’re done.

3-If the problem persists, press CTRL + SHIFT + A, and type “Un-inject Language / Reference“. And Double click on the second option, i.e. Un-inject Language/Reference.

4-Now uncheck the Language injection option. Click on apply and OK.

5- Go to File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart…

The Android Studio will now restart with modified settings. Hope this helps you to get rid from that AidlTokenType.import error.